# Console app to create web part pages for all document libraries

Tags: 2007, web-part-page, document-library

How do I create web part pages for all document libraries (all the document libraries starts with Eng_xxxxx and there are about 46 dob lib) in the current website
(http://localsharepoint/EngineeringDept/)?

The web part pages has same layout. Any links or ideas? I'm new to SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

You mean Publishing Pages? Andrew Connell wrote an article about it: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2006/11/15/5168.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If its is plain old Web Part Pages w/o publishing then it is just as easy as adding ASPX pages, with Web Part Zones, to the doclib and then use the SPLimitedWebPartManager to add and configure the Web Parts.